# Can we create a Custom Path For AWS API Gateway Execution logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sam

Currently, my API gateway execution logs are getting logged in cloud-watch in some random path of a particular format. Is there a way for me to customize that log path in SAM Template while deploying the API gateway ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of April 2021, execution logs are fully managed by AWS API Gateway and the log group name will be in form of `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{rest-api-id}/{stage_name}` and the format is pre-defined.

On a different note: You can define the CloudWatch target ARN and format of access logs though if you have this enabled but this is a different set of logs.

If you are using SAM, you can explicitly define your API using the [AWS::Serverless::Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html) resource type.  This type as a property called [AccessLogSetting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-stage-accesslogsetting.html) that allows you to provide the ARN of a CloudWatch group to send the the access logs to.

Also check out this guide which doesn't go into SAM automation but explains API Gateway logging configurations and what is possible, a good read.

https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/api-gateway-access-logs/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, the information in the link is pretty good, but it doesn't say how to redirect the execution logs

Comment: you are right, i did more digging and it's not possible to update execution logs ARN, I updated my answer